# How can I add alert message using alertcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am working on an open source application using Xcode 9.3.1 Swift 4.
There is a play button. When the user clicks on the play button the audio file downloads automatically before it starts playing. I want to add an alert message that alerts the user, shows the file size, and lets him accept or not to proceed with the download.

Here my audiobarview.xib code:

```
import GenericDataSources
import QueuePlayer
import UIKit

internal protocol AdvancedAudioOptionsViewControllerDelegate : AnyObject {
    internal func advancedAudioOptionsViewController(_ controller: AdvancedAudioOptionsViewController, finishedWith options: AdvancedAudioOptions)
}

internal class AdvancedAudioOptionsViewController : UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    weak internal var delegate: AdvancedAudioOptionsViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak internal var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak internal var contentView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak internal var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak internal var navigationBar: UINavigationBar!

    lazy internal var playButton: UIButton { get set }

    internal init(options: AdvancedAudioOptions)

    required internal init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)

    override internal func viewDidLoad()
    override internal func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool)
    override internal func viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    @IBAction internal func playButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
    @IBAction internal func dismissView(_ sender: Any)

    internal func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool
}

extension UIView {
    internal func round(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat)
}
```

Here is the audiofilesdownloader.swift code:

```
import BatchDownloader
import PromiseKit

class AudioFilesDownloader {
    let audioFileList: QariAudioFileListRetrieval
    let downloader: DownloadManager
    let ayahDownloader: AnyInteractor<AyahsAudioDownloadRequest, DownloadBatchResponse>

    private var response: DownloadBatchResponse?

    init(audioFileList: QariAudioFileListRetrieval,
         downloader: DownloadManager,
         ayahDownloader: AnyInteractor<AyahsAudioDownloadRequest, DownloadBatchResponse>) {
        self.audioFileList  = audioFileList
        self.downloader     = downloader
        self.ayahDownloader = ayahDownloader
    }

    func cancel() {
        response?.cancel()
        response = nil
    }

    func needsToDownloadFiles(qari: Qari, range: VerseRange) -> Bool {
        let files = filesForQari(qari, range: range)

        return !files.filter { !FileManager.documentsURL.appendingPathComponent($0.destinationPath).isReachable }.isEmpty
    }

    func getCurrentDownloadResponse() -> Promise<DownloadBatchResponse?> {
        if let response = response {
            return Promise(value: response)
        } else {
            return downloader.getOnGoingDownloads().then { batches -> DownloadBatchResponse? in
                let downloading = batches.first { $0.isAudio }

                self.createRequestWithDownloads(downloading)

                return self.response
            }
        }
    }

    func download(qari: Qari, range: VerseRange) -> Promise<DownloadBatchResponse?> {
        return ayahDownloader
            .execute(AyahsAudioDownloadRequest(range: range, qari: qari))
            .then(on: .main) { responses -> DownloadBatchResponse? in
                // wrap the requests
                self.createRequestWithDownloads(responses)

                return self.response
            }
    }

    private func createRequestWithDownloads(_ batch: DownloadBatchResponse?) {
        guard let batch = batch else { return }

        response = batch
        response?.promise.always { [weak self] in
            self?.response = nil
        }
    }

    func filesForQari(_ qari: Qari, range: VerseRange) -> [DownloadRequest] {
        return audioFileList.get(for: qari, range: range).map {
            DownloadRequest(url: $0.remote, resumePath: $0.local.stringByAppendingPath(Files.downloadResumeDataExtension), destinationPath: $0.local)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide implementation of the function which is actually downloading the file.

Comment: I added the audiofilesdownloader.swift code, please check @nikksindia

Comment: Nobody van do something please ? this is very important for me, even if I will need to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the filesize as a variable `filesize`

**Swift 4:**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Proceed with download?", message: "File size: \(filesize)", preferredStyle: .alert)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            // Leave empty, dismisses the alert
        }))

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Download Song", style: .default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
            // Code to download song
        }))

        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```